# Action on push notification tap in notification center

Tags: android, push, google-cloud-messaging

I'm testing GCM service to implement push notification in my app. When I receive a notification it is shown in the notification center. Now, when I tap on it, it opens the app and I'd like to load a url into a web view (the url is passed in the payload).
Any idea on how to accomplish it?

Comment: put the url in the intent bundle then get it from the bundle when the activity is launched

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that you have an intent service class that handles the incoming GCM message (as in the [official demo](https://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/gcm-client/GcmClient/src/main/java/com/google/android/gcm/demo/app/GcmIntentService.java)).

Let's assume that you pass the `url` from your server in a parameter called `url`.

When you create the intent that would start the activity, you add the url to the intent's extras.

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    String url = (String) extras.get("url");
    String msg = (String) extras.get("message");
    Intent activityIntent = new Intent(this, DemoActivity.class);
    activityIntent.putExtra ("url",url);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            activityIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_gcm)
    .setContentTitle("GCM Notification")
    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
    .bigText(msg))
    .setContentText(msg);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
}
```

When the activity is started, you can get the url from the extras of the intent and load it to your web view.

Comment: I'm getting The method putExtra(String, String) is undefined for the type PendingIntent on contentIntent.putExtra ("url",url);

Comment: @Enzoses Sorry about that. The putExtra should be done on the intent contained within the PendingIntent. See the updated answer.